# Jump between HTML file in python flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am new to flask and trying to use flask to build a webpage to display data from SQL.I already got some HTML written already. But I didn't figure out how to jump through HTML on flask just like those function in HTML. Here is the problem I have got

app.py

```
from flask import * 
from markupsafe import escape
app=Flask(`__`name`__`)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/main", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def main(name=None):
return render_template('main.html', name=name)
```

-templates --main.html

```
<li>

<a href="#">`Rules`</a>
<ul>

  
                    <li><a href="#">uuu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for('sub1') }}">yyy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for('sub2') }}">zzz</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for('sub3') }}">www</a></li>

</ul>
</li>
```

I tried to write jinja rather than original HTML file like this, but this doesn't works, using sub1 directly also doesn't work. All of sub<integer>.html and main.html are within templates folder
How can I jump to sub1 html when I have multiple

It can jump to multiple sub html directly by clicking yyy,zzz,www on the webpage

Comment: You have the right idea. Basically, each html page should have a flask route, which you would then link to when you want to jump to that page. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27539309/15368978) for more details.

Comment: @PatrickYoder Thanks, the question you refered help me solve my problem