# Redirect to other HTML file using Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, http-post

I have 2 HTML files, one I am using in the beginning, and what I want is that after the user clicks a button and a POST request comes into the code, it should change to another HTML page.

My current code (part of it):

```
...

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])                                
def test():
    output = request.get_json()
    print(output)
    render_template('secondform.html', static_folder='static')

...
```

But the problem is that this doesn't work...

How would I make it that it would that after a POST request has been detected, it would switch to a completely new HTML page.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Reposted from an answer: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27540234/7758804) from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27539309/7758804)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this simply check the [request.method](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#http-methods) and add logic accordingly for `GET` and `POST` :

```
from flask import request
@app.route('/test', methods=["POST", "GET"])                                
def test():
    if request.method == "POST"
        output = request.get_json()
        print(output)
        return render_template('secondform.html', static_folder='static')
    return render_template('<get_request_template_file>.html', static_folder='static') 
    #above will be executed on GET request and will render <get_request_template_file>.html
```

Comment: Is `<get_request_template_file>.html` the second form or the current form?

Comment: It should be the HTML form that initiates a POST request. So in this case, the `<get_request_template_file>.html` should be the one used in beginning.