# Created buttons in HTML to direct to other HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have created two buttons in my `index.html`. Now these buttons are directed at two other html files that are in the same folder, but when I click on those buttons, nothing happens. And my `index.html` file shows some errors that goes `; expected`.

Here is my code of `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flask and SQLite </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Build Web App Using Flask and SQLite</h1>
        <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for('join') }}';">Fill form to get updates</button><br/>
        <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for('participants') }}';">Check participant list</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Is your problem similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539309/how-do-i-create-a-link-to-another-html-page

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? `{{}}` syntax is not valid vanilla HTML.

Comment: @rensothearin no it's a little bit different. I already check that one. thanks for sharing by the way.

Comment: @cSharp i am doing this in my visual basic. I am trying to use flask to develop a simple web app

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Does this workaround help? [Making a <button> that's a link in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341011/making-a-button-thats-a-link-in-html)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. i found the bug. now its working. i didn't put the index.html in the same folder with other buttons. when I did so it works fine now